# Rubymine Rspec Debugger Error SegmentationFault

Tags: ruby, rspec, rubymine

I am rather suddenly getting the following error while running an rspec test:

> ```
> /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby -e at_exit{sleep(1)};$stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift)
> ```
>
> /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@rem2/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.6.0/bin/rdebug-ide
>   --disable-int-handler --evaluation-timeout 10 --rubymine-protocol-extensions --port 50027 --dispatcher-port 50028 -- /Users/username/Development/Rails/rem2/bin/rspec
>   /Users/username/Development/Rails/rem2/spec/background/verwaltungshonorar_abrechnung_job_spec.rb
>   --require teamcity/spec/runner/formatter/teamcity/formatter --format Spec::Runner::Formatter::TeamcityFormatter --example
>   "VerwaltungshonorarAbrechnungJob#perform_implementation führt den
>   VerwaltungshonorarAbrechnung-Job mit einem Unterhaltshonorar aus"
>       Testing started at 14:40 ...
>       Fast Debugger (ruby-debug-ide 0.6.0, debase 0.2.1, file filtering is supported) listens on 127.0.0.1:50027
>       Setting Eager Load to false
>       #Specs: Adapter using: PostgreSQL
>       Run options: include {:full_description=>/VerwaltungshonorarAbrechnungJob#perform_implementation\
>   führt\ den\ VerwaltungshonorarAbrechnung-Job\ mit\ einem\
>   Unterhaltshonorar\ aus/}
>       /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@rem2/gems/debase-0.2.1/lib/debase_internals.bundle:
>   [BUG] Segmentation fault at 0x00000000000438
>       ruby 2.2.0p0 (2014-12-25 revision 49005) [x86_64-darwin14]
>
> ```
> -- Crash Report log information --------------------------------------------
>    See Crash Report log file under the one of following:
>      * ~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter
>      * /Library/Logs/CrashReporter
>      * ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports
>      * /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports
>    for more details.
>
> -- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------
> c:0010 p:-17558197373282 s:0050 e:000049 TOP    [FINISH]
> c:0009 p:---- s:0048 e:000047 CFUNC  :require
> c:0008 p:0113 s:0044 e:000043 METHOD /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54
> c:0007 p:0042 s:0034 e:000033 TOP    /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@rem2/gems/debase-0.2.1/lib/debase.rb:4
> ```
>
> [FINISH]
>       c:0006 p:---- s:0032 e:000031 CFUNC  :require
>       c:0005 p:0113 s:0028 e:000027 METHOD /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54
>       c:0004 p:0042 s:0018 e:000017 TOP    /Applications/RubyMine.app/Contents/rb/gems/debug_preloader.rb:4
>   [FINISH]
>       c:0003 p:---- s:0016 e:000015 CFUNC  :require
>       c:0002 p:0113 s:0012 e:000011 METHOD /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54 [FINISH]
>       c:0001 p:0000 s:0002 E:001110 TOP    [FINISH]
>
> ```
> -- Ruby level backtrace information ----------------------------------------
> /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
> /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
> /Applications/RubyMine.app/Contents/rb/gems/debug_preloader.rb:4:in
> ```
>
> `<top (required)>'
>       /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in`require'
>       /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
>       /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@rem2/gems/debase-0.2.1/lib/debase.rb:4:in`
>   '
>       /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
>       /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in`require'
>
> ```
> -- Machine register context ------------------------------------------------
>  rax: 0x0000000000000030 rbx: 0x00007fc0b0f03ef0 rcx: 0x0000000000000000
>  rdx: 0xfffffffffffffff0 rdi: 0x0000000000000030 rsi: 0x0000000000000000
>  rbp: 0x00007fff59d4fe80 rsp: 0x00007fff59d4fe80  r8: 0x0000000000000017
>   r9: 0x00000000ffffff80 r10: 0x00007fff9ef5e400 r11: 0x00007fff8d128c20
>  r12: 0x00007fff79697070 r13: 0x00007fc0b0c06e00 r14: 0x0000000000000006
>  r15: 0x00007fff59d4ff60 rip: 0x0000000106bf9651 rfl: 0x0000000000010246
>
> -- C level backtrace information -------------------------------------------
> 0   ruby                                0x0000000106164b3b rb_vm_bugreport + 155
> 1   ruby                                0x0000000106009bd0 rb_bug_context + 480
> 2   ruby                                0x00000001060e1693 sigsegv + 83
> 3   libsystem_platform.dylib            0x00007fff8d127eaa _sigtramp + 26
> 4   libruby.2.3.0.dylib                 0x0000000106bf9651 ruby_xmalloc + 17
> 5   ???                                 0x00007fff59d4fea0 0x0 + 140734700519072
>
> -- Other runtime information -----------------------------------------------
>
> * Loaded script: /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@notification/bin/ruby_executable_hooks
>
> * Loaded features:
>
>     0 enumerator.so
>     1 rational.so
>     2 complex.so
>     3 encdb.so
>     4 trans/transdb.so
>     5 /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/unicode_normalize.rb
>     6 /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/x86_64-darwin14/rbconfig.rb
>     7 thread.rb
>     8 thread.so
>     9 /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/compatibility.rb
>    10 /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/defaults.rb
>    11 /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/deprecate.rb
>    12 /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/errors.rb
>    13 /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/version.rb
>    14 /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/requirement.rb
>    15 /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/platform.rb
>    16 /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/basic_specification.rb
>    17 /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/stub_specification.rb
>    18 /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/util/stringio.rb
>    19 /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/specification.rb
>    20 /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/exceptions.rb
>    21 /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb
>    22 /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb
>    23 /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb
>    24 /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems.rb
>
> [NOTE]
> You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
> Bug reports are welcome.
> Don't forget to include the above Crash Report log file.
> For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html
> ```

Debase (0.2.2.beta6, 0.2.1) and ruby-debug-ide (0.6.0) cannot be updated further. Anyone has an idea why it is somehow using ruby 2.2.0 instead of 2.3.0? In the settings I set it to the right version. The test runs fine in the console.

**EDIT: The problem solved itself. No idea how.. :-(**

Answer (score 1):

The problem was, that rvm was using ruby 2.2.0 by default. (ruby-2.2.0@notification) Notification is a connected project which is used by some of the tests. It usually uses ruby 2.3.0, like my main project. Once I uninstalled 2.2.0 and set the default to 2.3.0 (`rvm use --default ruby-2.3.0`), everything worked perfectly.